# Is it bad practice to disable Antivirus software on a build server for more performance?

Tags: security, azure-devops, build, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to optimize our software builds (Azure DevOps Server Build Agents) as far as I can and was curious, if disabling Windows Defender on our Windows Servers would be good or bad practice?

In our case, `Msmpeng.exe` takes about 10-15 % (CPU utilization) when a build is running.

If I exlude the agents processes (`AgentService.exe`, `Agent.Worker.exe`, `Agent.Listener.exe`) and the work directory, I'm sure, `Msmpeng.exe` would get down to 5 % or less which should result in faster compile times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it`s up to you:

1. If you use isolated build agents and build only internal solutions. You may disable antivirus or exclude the build agent work folder.
2. If you download some external packages, you have to use antiviruses. Additionally, consider using Snyk or WhiteSource.